# having an integer and printing out the hexadecimal in MIPS

Tags: assembly, mips, mars-simulator

If I have an integer, what is the line of code(s) to print out the integer into hexadecimal? I know you use 34 as the command but im not sure about the rest of it

Answer (score 4):

The "34" you're referring to is the syscall number for "print integer in hexadecimal" in the `mars` simulator.

The syscall reference is: http://courses.missouristate.edu/kenvollmar/mars/help/syscallhelp.html

Assuming your number was in a register, say, `$t5`, the sequence would be:

```
    move    $a0,$t5                 # put number into correct reg for syscall
    li      $v0,34                  # syscall number for "print hex"
    syscall                         # issue the syscall
```