# How to Print Hex Value in MIPS using SPIM Editor

Tags: printing, hex, mips, spim

I want to print hex value in MIPS using SPIM Simulation Editor, but I found some answers for MARS Simulation Editor. In MARS, I can do it as "li $v0, 34". How can I do this statement for SPIM editor? Thanks for helps.

Comment: In MARS you find all documentation about `syscalls` and macros in `? help` . I only guess that SPIM also should has such a documentation.

Comment: You'll have to write your own function for that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is my MIPS base converter printing out the values from a previous loop after the current values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37153381/why-is-my-mips-base-converter-printing-out-the-values-from-a-previous-loop-after) has working code.