# MIPS ASM: How to convert a binary number to a hex one

Tags: assembly, mips

I am having a little bit of trouble understanding how to convert a binary string such as '0x0123beef' to its hexadecimal form, just 0x0123beef in mips.

I understand how to approach the problem, but I am very confused about how to actually do it. as a matter of fact, I managed to put some code together

```
    .data 
 Hex: .word 0x0123b5ef
 ans: .asciiz "\nHexadecimal equivalent: " 
 result: .space 10
.text   

     main:

     la $t2, Hex 

    la $a0, ans
    li $v0, 4
     syscall



     li $t0, 8               # counter
     la $t3, result      
     Loop:
     beqz $t0, Exit      # branch to exit if counter is equal to zero
     rol $t2, $t2, 4     # rotate 4 bits to the left

     and $t4, $t2, 0xf           # mask with 1111
     ble $t4, 9, Sum     # if less than or equal to nine, branch to sum
     addi $t4, $t4, 0x37           # if greater than nine, add 55
     b End
     Sum:
         addi $t4, $t4, 0x30   # add 48 to result
     End: 
     sb $t4, 0($t3)          # store hex digit into result
     addi $t3, $t3, 1        # increment address counter
     sub $t0, $t0, 1       # decrement loop counter
     j Loop
      Exit:

     la $a0, result 

    li $v0, 4
     syscall

     la $v0, 10
     syscall
```

I am struggling to make this actually display 0123beef in the first place. It yields 10010000 everytime I run it. After I solve this problem, I want to know how to put the "0x" part at the beginning.

Thank you!

Comment: You only did `la $t2, Hex` which loads the address not the value. You are missing a `lw $t2, ($t2)`. You can store the `0x` in the buffer right away, and start writing the digits offset by 2.

Comment: `0x10010000` might well be the correct address of the start of the data section in Mars, where you put `Hex`.

Comment: Related: [Why is my MIPS base converter printing out the values from a previous loop after the current values?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37153381) for working int -> hex code.