# How to print a hexadecimal in a file in MIPS assembly?

Tags: assembly, mips

```
.data
hex_format: .asciiz "%X\n"    # format string for printing integer in hexadecimal
filename:   .asciiz "output.txt"

.text
main:
    # assume integer value is stored in register $t0

    # open file for writing
    li $v0, 13          # set syscall code to open file
    la $a0, filename    # set file name to open
    li $a1, 1           # set file mode to write
    li $a2, 0           # set file permissions to default
    syscall             # call operating system routine, file descriptor returned in $v0
    li $t0,36
    move $a0, $v0       # set file descriptor to argument register for print syscall
    li $v0, 34          # set syscall code to print integer in hexadecimal format
    move $a1, $t0       # set input value to integer register
    la $a2, hex_format  # set format string to hexadecimal format specifier
    syscall             # call operating system routine to write integer to file in hexadecimal format

    # close file
    move $a0, $v0       # set file descriptor to argument register for close syscall
    li $v0, 16          # set syscall code to close file
    syscall             # call operating system routine to close file

    li $v0, 10          # set syscall code to exit program
    syscall             # call operating system routine to exit program
```

---

I converted an integer to hexadecimal and then I don't know how to print it in the file.

Comment: System call 34 doesn't take a file descriptor. At least not if this is MARS. It takes a single argument: the number to print. If you want to print it to a file you'll probably have to write your own function to convert the number into a string, and then write that string to the file using system call 15.

Comment: syscall 34 prints to the console, not to a file.  There's been a internal conversion to hex for printing, but it is not accessible to the program: it only goes to the console and is otherwise discarded.  MARS/QtSPim don't have printf, sprintf, or anything that takes format string, like %x.

Comment: [Why is my MIPS base converter printing out the values from a previous loop after the current values?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37154456) has an answer with int->string functions.  Make a string in a buffer and write it to a file.